# Why does zsh get root while bash does not?

Tags: bash, shell, zsh

I'm a little confused. If I copy zsh into tmp and change the Set-UID bit `chmod u+s` change the user and then run the copied zsh. If I run `whoami` I get root. If I do the same thing to bash, after I run bash I get the user I was logged into before hand. Is there any reason for why they act different?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is an intentional feature of bash; to disable it, run bash with the `-p` option.

In more detail: when you run a setuid binary, the process's effective uid (euid) is set to that of the binary, but its real uid isn't changed. bash detects the difference, and (if the `-p` option wasn't passed) it resets its euid to the real uid.

From the [bash manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Startup-Files.html#Bash-Startup-Files):

> **Invoked with unequal effective and real UID/GIDs**
>
> If Bash is started with the effective user (group) id not equal to the real user (group) id, and the `-p` option is not supplied, no startup files are read, shell functions are not inherited from the environment, the `SHELLOPTS`, `BASHOPTS`, `CDPATH`, and `GLOBIGNORE` variables, if they appear in the environment, are ignored, and the effective user id is set to the real user id. If the `-p` option is supplied at invocation, the startup behavior is the same, but the effective user id is not reset.